# Is there a way to force all web request to go through a proxy?

Tags: .net, networking, powershell, configuration, proxy

I'm working in an office and must use http proxy to access internet.

Is there any $PSvariable or environment variable that would tell powershell to use http proxy when requesting an external ressource ? (like http_proxy env var in linux : 
`http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/

export http_proxy` )

I know i can do it for webclient

```
$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
$proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$web.proxy = $proxy
```

, do it for pssessions

```
$PSSessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType IEConfig -ProxyAuthentication Negotiate -ProxyCredential Domain\User
```

but sometimes i cant find any solution for example how to use `update-help |save-help`  through proxy?

Comment: I don't have to do anything special to access the web via a proxy on my system. The settings used by IE are picked by up PowerShell and pretty much everything else on my system automatically. I don't know how (or even if) the proxy is doing authentication though - that may be the difference.

Comment: oh oh maybe you've hit something ... as i dont use ie the proxy settings can be wrong.Will test tommorow and let you know. Thank you

Comment: @alroc thanks this is working fine after redefining proxy settings in IE. Make an answer and i'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell (and most other things on Windows) will use the proxy settings configured in Internet Explorer. Set that up properly and it should work; you may need to access a few sites with IE to make sure any authentication is taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

Answering because I have insufficient reputation to comment.

This doesn't work if you use a proxy configuration file, rather than setting the proxy settings directly.  In fact, I can't get it to work even when specifying the proxy directly.

The only solution I have seen to this is from Ravikanth Chaganti

[Save-Help woes and solution](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=2501)

There is a MS Connect request to have this fixed:  [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/730195/save-help-failure-unable-to-connect-to-help-content-error-while-connected-to-internet-via-corporate-proxy-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
I use the following script for Update-Help for Computers behind a proxy with authentication:
# -------------------------------
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$proxyUserName  = Read-Host -Prompt "Proxy User Name"
$proxySecPasswd = Read-Host -Prompt "Password für $proxyUserName"  -AsSecureString
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($proxyUserName, $proxySecPasswd)
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = $credentials
Update-Help -UICulture 'en-US'
# -------------------------------
```